# Custom key URI support for AES-128 encryption in google cloud transcoder

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

Not able to create a HLD stream with AES 128 encryption based on the public document

Issue Summary: Customer is looking at using our transcoding API to provide DRM capabilities to one of their learning platform. They require HLS and DASH with AES 128 bit encryption . I have followed the public documentation but not getting the m3u8 or TS files . The job created from 'preset/web-hd' is working correctly.

Please help me by providing exact sample codes for the above scenario. Please provide with complete code required for HLS and DASh with AES 128 bit encryption.

```
Project Number: project-number
Job ID: job-id
Location:
Job Config elementaryStreams: [ { key: 'video-stream1', videoStream: { codec: 'h264', heightPixels: 720, widthPixels: 1280, bitrateBps: 2500000, frameRate: 60, }, }, ], muxStreams: [ { "key": "360p-my-video-ts", "fileName": "360p-my-video.ts", "container": "ts", "elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream1" ], "encryption": { "key": "aabbccddeeff11223344556677889900", "iv": "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff", "sampleAes": { "keyUri": "skd://00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the "manifest" section on the bottom of the "configure-drm" link.

Also please refer to https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/configure-drm (there are some samples)

The Transcoder API is mostly focused on supporting DRM systems, when you use your own key you have to specify full path to the key, unfortunately do to some validation in our API it is not possible right now, we will work on allowing custom URLs.

We have a fix ready (this will allow customers to specify key URIs with HTTP protocol as well), but it will take a few weeks to roll out to Prod. If you want to try it out right now you can generate the manifest with sdk:// URI in it and replace it with the HTTP link to the key in the manifest, but I'd suggest to wait until the fix is available in Prod.

In the meantime here are some issues with your config:

The decryption key should be in binary rather than plain text
In the job config you are using Sample-AES encryption that is supposed to be used with Fairplay, you should use AES-128 instead